# Validate data uploaded from excel file into gridview using validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a gridview that is filled from an excel file the user is uploading. Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" SkinID="GridView" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="false"
                EmptyDataText="Data not found." AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
                OnRowEditing="gvData_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvData_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gvData_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="gvData_RowDeleting"> 
                <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>'  CssClass="datepicker"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDate" runat="server" CssClass="validator"  ErrorMessage="Required" Display="Dynamic"  ControlToValidate="txtDate"/>
                        <asp:CompareValidator id="dateValidator" runat="server" CssClass="validator" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date."/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ref Number" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRefNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ref Number")%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRefNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ref Number")%>' />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revRefNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRefNumber" CssClass="validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Numbers only"
                            ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$"/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

As you can see, I have few validators on each field, by they kick into action only when the relevant textbox is being edited. For example, I'm making sure that a textbox in the date column contains a valid date value after the user finishes editing it. The problem is that the user can insert any data into these cells when the data is first uploaded from the excel file - the validators are completely "bypassed".

I would like to know if there's a way to apply and enforce these validators on the uploaded data.

Comment: Are you trying to say , when you are binding Data with the gridview you are trying to Validate Data with these validation in gridview?

Comment: @Rahul Something like that...

Comment: You can not validate at the time of binding by using gridview validation's. You need to validate your Dataset or Datatable before binding it to the gridiview.

Comment: But that would mean that I need to replicate each validator... I truly hope there's a more elegant way of doing that...

Comment: Suppose you need to validate a Date Column of a dataset, you can apply Regex to that particular column(Date)  of the Dataset to filter result's.